# Is Cartan subalgebra of a Lie algebra unique?

Tags: lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a Lie algebra. Is Cartan subalgebra of $\mathfrak{g}$ unique? I see in some places it is written "Let $\mathfrak{h}$ be a Cartan subalgebra of $\mathfrak{g}$".

Comment: You are right, it is not unique

Comment: Why it is unique? It seems that $\mathfrak{g}$ is just all diagonal matrices in $\mathfrak{g}$.

Comment: Does my example make sense?

Comment: Cartan subalgebra is unique up to the adjoint action of the corresponding group $G$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is an example. If $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{R})$, then both of 
$$
\mathfrak{h}_1 = \mathbb{R}\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix} \quad , \quad \mathfrak{h}_2 = \mathbb{R}\begin{bmatrix}0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
$$
are Cartan subalgebras.

**Add**: To add a bit more detail: It isn't too difficult to check that both of these subalgebras are (1) nilpotent and (2) they are both equal to their own normalizers in $\mathfrak{g}$.

Comment: I know this is a bit late, but to see that the above Cartan subalgebras are nilpotent, shouldn't the determinant of each of the matrices equal zero? But they are not. (I'm just checking the details you have suggested above.)

Comment: @math-visitor: There is something called a nilpotent matrix (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilpotent_matrix). Here indeed you need the determinant to be zero. However, here we are talking about nilpotent Lie algebras: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilpotent_Lie_algebra. Note for this that all the commutators are zero.

Comment: Great, thanks! =)

Answer (score 3):

You can think in terms of the Lie group, any element is in a maximal torus and any two maximal torus are conjugate to each other. For simple-connected Lie groups the maximal torus correspond to the Cartan subalgebra. So one should expect many different copies of Cartan subalgebra in the Lie algebra. But they are all isomorphic.

Comment: "any element is in a maximal torus"—only if you have a *compact* Lie group.  (Why do you restrict to simply connected to establish a bijection between maximal tori and CSA's?  I only know about linear Lie groups, but there neither the Lie algebra, nor the collection of tori, sees the fundamental group—although of course individual tori do.)

Answer (score 1):

No, Cartan algebra of a Lie algebra may not be unique.  But any two Cartan algebras are conjugate to each other.

Comment: This is not true in general. It is true for complex semisimple Lie algebras but it doesn't hold for real semisimple Lie algebras. For example sl(2,R) has two conjugacy classes which you can check as one group have positive Killing form while the others have negative Killing form.