# Union of Cartan subalgebras

Tags: lie-algebras

Let $L$ be a semisimple Lie algebra over the field $F$ of characteristics zero. Let $H_1,H_2$ be any two of its Cartan subalgebras (that exist, are maximal toral, self-normalizing, Abelian). Let $\mathfrak{A}(H_1,H_2)$ be minimal Lie subalgebra of $L$ that contains $H_1$ and $H_2$. I can not find in the literature anything about $\mathfrak{A}(H_1,H_2)$. I tried concluding something myself, but I got nowhere. Is there any book or paper that object $\mathfrak{A}(H_1,H_2)$ was studied? Thankies in advance!

What I tried (this is new idea) is using Theorem 4.1.3 in

Veeravalli S. Varadarajan: $\textit{Lie Groups, Lie Algebras and their Representations}$, Springer-Verlag, 1984.

as there is is clearly said that all Cartan subalgebras are $\mathfrak{h}_X$ (his notations, kind of generalized centralizer) but as I mentioned in previous paragraph these objects $\mathfrak{h}_X$ are harder to control then centralizers and I do not even know the answer to (simpler as it turns out) question:

If we take two elements $x,y \in L$, and denote $C_L(x),C_L(y)$ its centralizer and with $\mathfrak{C}(x,y)$ the minimal subalgebra of $L$ that contains $C_L(x)$ and $C_L(y)$ then what do we know in general about $\mathfrak{C}(x,y)$?

I would appreciate answers in forms of general lemmas from books or papers rather than some examples, thankies!

Comment: What do you mean by "its" Cartan subalgebras? There are more than $H_1$ and $H_2$ in general.

Comment: Conjugacy doesn't mean that it doesn't matter which ones you pick. After all you can have two distinct Cartan subalgebras that overlap to codimension 1

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thankies for the comment! That just means "any two Cartan subalgebras of $L$".

Comment: @Callum Intersection of Cartan subalgebras also is very interesting. I wanted just some general result nothing fancy.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/134901/is-cartan-subalgebra-of-a-lie-algebra-unique), for example, for $L=\mathfrak{sl}_2(\Bbb R)$, and determine $\mathfrak{A}$.

Comment: In Humphreys, it is actually said that the Cartan subalgebras over fields of characteristic zero are exactly centralizers of (regular) semisimple elements. Result from Varadarajan in the question is more general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't want examples, but that's what I'm gonna give, for I haven't been doing research related to Lie algebras for ages, and wouldn't know what buzzwords to use to search the publications.

As examples I proffer pairs of Cartan algebras that behave kinda extremally in the sense of your question. This was inspired by the comment Callum made.

So consider the simple Lie algebra $L=\mathfrak{so}_m(\Bbb{C})$ where $m=2\ell+1$ is an odd integer, $\ell\ge2$. I define it as the Lie algebra of antisymmetric $m\times m$ matrices. Let $E_{ij}$ be the $m\times m$ matrix with its sole non-zero entry a $1$ at position $(i,j)$. Let $S_{ij}:=E_{ij}-E_{ji}$ be its antisymmetric
counterpart. The matrices $S_{ij},1\le i<j\le m$ span $L$, and somewhat redundantly
we also have the matrices $S_{ji}=-S_{ij}$.

It is easy to verify that the elements $S_{ij}$ are all $\mathrm{ad}$-semisimple.
As the matrices $S_{12}$, $S_{34}$, $S_{56}$, $\ldots$, $S_{2\ell-1;2\ell}$
commute, and there are $\ell$ of them, they span a Cartan subalgebra $H_1$.

Another Cartan subalgebra $H_2$ is spanned by $S_{23}$, $S_{45}$, $S_{67}$, $\ldots$,
$S_{2\ell;2\ell+1}$. Observe that $H_1$ and $H_2$ intersect trivially.

A third Cartan subalgebra $H_3$ I will use is almost the same as $H_2$. I just
replace the first generating matrix $S_{23}$ with $S_{12}$.
So the subspaces $H_2$ and $H_3$ have a codimension one intersection.

On with the subalgebras the pairs generate. A tool I will use is that whenever $i,j,k$ are three distinct indices, then $S_{ij},S_{jk}$ and $S_{ki}$ span a copy
of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{so}_3(\Bbb{C})$, and we have the familiar commutator
relations
$$[S_{ij},S_{jk}]=S_{ik},\quad [S_{jk},S_{ki}]=S_{ji},\quad [S_{ki},S_{ij}]=S_{kj}.$$
In other words, we get the third (up to sign) as the commutator of the other two of any such triple.

- The smallest Lie algebra $\mathfrak{A}(H_1,H_2)$ containing both $H_1$ and $H_2$
  is then actually all of $L$. This follows easily from the above observation. We get
  $S_{13}$ as the commutator of $S_{12}\in H_1$ and $S_{23}\in H_2$. Similarly for the other matrices $S_{i;i+2}$, $i=1,2,\ldots,m-2$. By induction on $d$ we then similarly get all the other matrices of the form $S_{i;i+d}$ with a difference $d$
  in the indices as commutators of matrices already known to be in $\mathfrak{A}(H_1,H_2)$.
- On the other hand $\mathfrak{A}(H_2,H_3)$ is much smaller. We easily see that all we need to add to the subspace sum $H_2+H_3$ is the commutator $S_{13}=[S_{12},S_{23}]$. In other words $\mathfrak{A}(H_2,H_3)$ is a direct sum of the algebra $\langle S_{12},S_{23},S_{13}\rangle\simeq \mathfrak{so}_3(\Bbb{C})$ and a toral subalgebra spanned by $S_{45},S_{67},\ldots,S_{2\ell;2\ell+1}$.

---

It is easy to imagine that something similar might happen in the general case also. The intersection $H_1\cap H_2$ becomes uninteresting, but the rest generate something else. It would not suprise me if something like the above Levi decomposition above would always come out, but I'm too ignorant to be sure.

Comment: Thankies! Yes, the point is that in fields of characteristics zero (the case I am interested in) there is more precise statement by Humphreys that Cartan subalgebras are exactly the centralizers of regular semisimple elements, and of union and intersection of centralizers we do not know much and anything can happen!

Comment: You're welcome. I would guess that somebody somewhere sometimes has looked at what happens in general, but I don't know the answer. It may be worth your while to ask at [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/). Though if Dietrich Burde didn't say more right away, then it may be that nobody there can settle this either. If you end up posting it there also, please link the two versions of the question as a courtesy. That we people don't need to duplicate each others writings :-)